# Is it possible to use Neo4j OGM Converter as a Spring @Component?

Tags: neo4j, converters, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have a custom converter annotated as a @Component and it depends on MyBean which is injected by Spring via @Autowired at boot time.

MyEntity has a field MyObject to be converted by that converter. OGM will call toEntityAttribute from MyObjectToStringConverter as soon as I retrieve MyEntity from Neo4j. However, I'm getting a NPE. It seems OGM does not reuse my converter created by Spring and MyBean dependency is always NULL.

Should OGM be able to get my converter from Spring context?

Is there a way MyBean could be initialized by OGM?

If not, can I register a converter by myselft?

```
@NodeEntity
class MyEntity {

    @Convert(MyObjectToStringConverter.class)
    private MyObject myObject;
    ...
}

@Component
class MyObjectToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyObject, String> {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

    @Override
    public String toGraphProperty(MyObject value) {
        return value.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public MyObject toEntityAttribute(String value) {
        return myBean.convert(value); // myBean is NULL
    }
}

...
repository.find(myEntityID) // NPE from MyObjectToStringConverter


java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.myproject.mvc.converter.MyObjectToStringConverter.toEntityAttribute(MyObjectToStringConverter.java:25) 
    at org.myproject.mvc.converter.MyObjectToStringConverter.toEntityAttribute(MyObjectToStringConverter.java:12) 
    at org.neo4j.ogm.entityaccess.FieldWriter.write(FieldWriter.java:64) 
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.writeProperty(GraphEntityMapper.java:162) 
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.setProperties(GraphEntityMapper.java:127) 
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.mapNodes(GraphEntityMapper.java:108) 
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:92) 
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:67) 
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.SessionResponseHandler.loadById(SessionResponseHandler.java:161) 
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.load(LoadOneDelegate.java:45) 
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.load(LoadOneDelegate.java:36) 
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.load(Neo4jSession.java:99) 
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryImpl.findOne(GraphRepositoryImpl.java:60) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) 
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468) 
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) 
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) 
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) 
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.findOne(Unknown Source) 
    at org.myproject.mvc.service.AbstractService.find(AbstractService.java:40)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OGM will not get the converter from the Spring context- it has no dependencies at all on Spring. Perhaps you can use Springs ConversionService?

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_spring_s_conversionservice

Comment: I followed the doc, but my converter is not found. My mapping: @ Convert(graphPropertyType = String.class) MyObject myObject; I created 2 converters using Spring Converter for String <--> MyObject. They also are annotated as @ Component. In my @ Configuration class I added the @ Bean ConversionService conversionService() as described into the doc. Return from getConverter = NO_MATCH. Exp: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.String to type org.myprojectcore.MyObject<?> – Jonathan D'Orleans 36 mins ago

Comment: SDN will just use converters provided by the conversion service but you have to register the converter with the conversion service such as https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/4.0.x/spring-data-neo4j/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/integration/conversion/ConversionServiceTest.java#L99 but I think that defeats the purpose of the autowired bean. Is there a way to register converters with the conversion service in some other manner so that your bean is injected? Not familiar with this